# Rails cache_classes needs to be off to load new classes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my Rails application I have some classes under the `/lib` folder:

```rb
/lib/ems
/lib/ems/client.rb
/lib/ems/credentials.rb
/lib/ems/v2/base.rb
/lib/ems/v2/policy.rb
```

And all classes are autoloaded in my application with:

```rb
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/"]
```

If I call: `Rails.application.instance_variable_get(:"@_all_autoload_paths")`

I can clearly see all my classes are being loaded correctly and they work fine in development.

However when in non-development environments, I get the `NameError undefined constant` for some of the classes under my `/lib` folder (not all of them, just some of them).

What I noticed is that if turn off class caching like so:

```rb
config.cache_classes = false
```

Then those classes will work fine and can be used without any issue... so it seems that it's not a problem with the autoloading, but rather a caching problem...

If I turn the `cache_classes` back on again, it then fails straight away.

How can I make it so that Rails can see these classes without having to turn this off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the directory to the eager_load_paths as well.

```
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/"]
config.eager_load_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/"]
```

See [Don't forget about eager_load when extending autoload paths](https://blog.arkency.com/2014/11/dont-forget-about-eager-load-when-extending-autoload/) from Arkency for an excellent (if somewhat dated) rundown on the details.

Comment: But we have about 20+ classes inside that folder and all of those are working fine... why do I suddenly need to use `eager_load_paths` to use these new classes?

Comment: Using `config.eager_load_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/"] ` does fix the issue (you don't need to use `autoload_paths` as well... but I'm confused why this hasn't been a problem for other classes in that folder until recently.

Comment: I don't have really good answer there unfortunately. I don't know if there is any change between Zeitwork and the classic autoloader which could explain it.